# How to update state using settimeout function inside loop in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating react app to visualize sorting arhorithms and I stopped on this problem. I'm looping through all elements of array from bars state and I want to swap them (for test purposes). This is not working excatly as I wanted, because it "ignores" `setTimeout` function and does it immediately. I tried something with setBars but it is not working too. How can I make this so swapping will happen after timeout set in `setTimeout` function?

```
const [bars, setBars] = useState([23, 63, 236, 17, 2]);

const swap = (arr, i, j) => {
 let temp = arr[i];
 arr[i] = arr[j];
 arr[j] = temp;
};

for (let i = 0; i < bars.length - 1; i++) {
 setTimeout(() => {
  swap(bars, i, i + 1);
 }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: You need to call setBars(arr) after swapping right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to use a `useEffect` hook to start the process when the component mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...code here...
}, []);
```

The empty dependencies array at the end says "only run this when the component first mounts."

Within it, your code would schedule the timer callbacks:

```
for (let i = 0; i < bars.length - 1; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setBars(bars => {
            // Copy the current array
            const newBars = [...bars];
            // Do the swap
            swap(newBars, i, i + 1);
            // Set the state by returning the update
            return newBars;
        });
    }, 2000 * (i + 1));
}
```

Note that that uses the callback form of `setBars`, so that you're operating on the then-current state (instead of `bars`, which is only the array used during the first mount, since your function is only called when that first mount occurs).

Also note that the interval is `2000 * (i + 1)` rather than just `2000`. That's so each callback occurs 2000ms after the last one, since they're all being scheduled at once.

Another important aspect of the above is that it uses `let` within the `for`, so each loop body gets its **own** `i` variable. (If the code used `var`, or `let` outside the `for`, all the callbacks would share the same `i` variable, which would have the value `bars.length`.)

---

Alternatively, I think I might take this approach:

Since you want to update both `i` and `bars` at the same time and since it's best to use the callback form of the state setter when doing updates asynchronously (as with `setTimeout`), I'd combine `i` and `bars` into a single state item (whereas I'd normally keep them separate):

```
const [barState, setBarState] = useState({i: 0, bars: [23, 63, 236, 17, 2]});
```

Then you'd use a `useEffect` hook to kick the process off when your component mounts and then do it again after each change to `barState`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...code here...
}, [barState]);
```

The dependencies array containing `barState` at the end says "run this on component mount and every time `barState` changes."

Within it, your code would schedule the timer callbacks:

```
if (barState.i < barState.bars.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setBarState(({i, bars}) => {
            // Copy the current array
            bars = [...bars];
            // Do the swap
            swap(bars, i, i + 1);
            // Set the state by returning the update
            ++i;
            return {i, bars};
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const swap = (arr, i, j) => {
    let temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
};

function Example() {
    const [barState, setBarState] = useState({i: 0, bars: [23, 63, 236, 17, 2]});

    useEffect(() => {
        if (barState.i < barState.bars.length - 1) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setBarState(({i, bars}) => {
                    // Copy the current array
                    bars = [...bars];
                    // Do the swap
                    swap(bars, i, i + 1);
                    // Set the state by returning the update
                    ++i;
                    return {i, bars};
                });
            }, 2000);
        }
    }, [barState]);

    return <div>{barState.bars.join(", ")}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation and quick answer :)

Comment: If you have a better idea I will be happy to see that too :)

Comment: @MateuszKozak - I've updated with the way I think I'd be inclined to do it, which is slightly different. :-)

Comment: It's cool to see another solution, but I will be implementing sorting algorithms, so I don't know that it would be a good idea to this in that way. For now, I will stick with first the solution, it's more readable for me and will be easier to implement in other algorithms.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @MateuszKozak - No worries either way! I've added back the first one for anyone who wants to see it. Happy coding!